# XPath - select nodes by analyzing following sibllings

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have the following XML document,

```
<doc>
    <h1>aa</h1>
    <p>bb</p>
    <p>cc</p>

    <h1>dd</h1>
    <p>ee</p>
    <h2>ff</h2>
    <h2>gg</h2>

    <h1>jj</h1>
    <p>kk</p>
    <p>ll</p>

    <h1>hh</h1>
    <h2>ii</h2>
    <p>jj</p>
</doc>
```

I need to write an XPath query to get `<h1>` nodes where there are following-siblings `<h2>` nodes exist before appear another `<h1>`node. In this case 2nd and 4th `<h1>` nodes should be selected. (`<h2>` nodes exist in following-sibligs before another `<h1>`node).

I tried to do this hours but could not think of any proper solution to get those nodes?

Can anyone suggest a method for how can I do this?

Comment: *2nd and 4th nodes* - from what? What are  those nodes in in the example?

Comment: @splash58, sorry for the mistake. I've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just find h2 and take preceding h1

```
 //h2/preceding-sibling::h1[1]
```

result

```
Element='<h1>dd</h1>'
Element='<h1>hh</h1>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Select such h1 nodes that have h2 as first following sibling among h1 and h2 nodes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/doc">
        <xsl:for-each select="h1[following-sibling::*[self::h1 or self::h2][1][self::h2]]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XPath is declarative, i.e. in most cases you can easily convert your initial query directly to XPath with minimal efforts.